# Don't want string to be generated if already in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little situation here. If in my database in my "Session" Table if I have the data below:

```
SessionId

C
```

Then what happens with my code is that it would not display the string above when user generates a new string as that it is already in the database. This works fine for example above.

The problem I have though is that if I have multiple sessions(exams), then in the database below it will display the strings as below in the database:

```
SessionId

C1
C2
C3
```

The above is for 3 exams. But the problem is that the string "C" can still be generated in the code below. What my question is that if there is a number at the end of the string like the table above, then how can I not generate the string as it is still in the database? The strings will always be 1 character long:

```
          function id_generator(){ 

              $id = ""; 
              $a = array( "A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F" , "G" , "H" , "I" , "J" , "K" , "L" , "M" , "N" , "O" , "P" , "Q" , "R" , "S" , "T" , "U" , "V" , "W" , "X" , "Y" , "Z" ); 

          for( $i = 0 ; $i < 1 ; $i++ ){ $r = rand( 0 , 25 );
           $id .= $a[ $r ]; 

       }

       return $id;

       };

       $is_there = true;

          while( $is_there ){
        $id = id_generator(); // your function to generate id;
        $result = "SELECT SessionId FROM Session WHERE SessionId LIKE ?";
        $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($result);
        $id = $id . '%';
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
        $stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId);

        $stmt->store_result();

        $stmtnum = $stmt->num_rows();

        if($stmtnum == 0) {
        $is_there = false;
    }
    }

....

</body>
<form>

 <p><strong>1: Your Assessment ID: </strong><span id="idFont"><?php echo $id; ?></span></p>

....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use `like`?

```
$result = "SELECT SessionId FROM Session WHERE SessionId LIKE ?";
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($result);
$id = $id . '%';
$stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
```

Comment: I tried to use a LIKE statement before with a CONCAT but couuldn't get it working. But I will try it your way and see if it works.

Comment: I actuallyy echo $id so if I did what you stated, it still generates the string but shows it as `C%`. I know the LIKE statement would work but have you got another possiblity on changing the LIKE statement so it could work?

Comment: what are you trying to? do you want to find if `C` already exist? whether the table has `C` or `C1234`?

Comment: Yes that is what I want to do, if a string already exists (e.g. `C`, `C1`, `C2` etc) then in the id_generator function it should not output string `C` as it is already in the database

Comment: the query is working [*click here*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c38740/1). i think the problem is with you generator.

Comment: can you also try `$stmt->bind_param("1",$id);`

Comment: I tried the `$stmt->bind_param("1",$id);` but still generating the string. Like I said if in the database the string was `C`, it would not generate the string C again. But instead in the database if the string is `C1`, `C2`, `C3` etc, then it generates string C still when it shouldn't do

Comment: I updated code above to included your answer into the code so you can now see what it looks like

Comment: Hi, John have got any more ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get you but perhaps something like

```
if not Exists(Select * From Session Where SessionID Like 'C[0123456789]')
begin
  insert Session(SessionID) Values(?)
end
```

'C[0123456789] isa straing starting with C followed by anyone of '0' to '9' and nothing else